# Amazon Instance Network Out Spike (Attacked?)

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I've been developing a website on a Micro EC2 Instance.  This morning, it stopped responding and when I went to the AWS console, it showed  that there had been a spike in Networking Out.

I don't have any traffic to speak of yet and I'm not scrapping in an automated fashion.

Does this mean that someone found my site and DOS attacked me or something along those lines?

Thanks

Comment: amazon has been having issues all morning - http://status.aws.amazon.com/?a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of Amazon's datacenters suffered an outage today and it is affecting several large companies.

Please check http://status.aws.amazon.com/ for more information. It's possible that you are being affected by this.

Comment: Thank you tomas.  I should have looked that up, but being a new to server admin, I just assumed that I had screwed up, not Amazon. I appreciate the non-snarky comment

Answer (score -1):

http://status.aws.amazon.com/

Also, this question doesn't belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: Why doesn't it belong? Granted I should have looked up the status of AWS but it was pretty likely (given my lack of experience deploying a site) that I had screwed up.  If so, why not get an answer from the SO community...

Comment: StackOverflow is for *programming* questions, your question is more suited for ServerFault. Check the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq